# How to properly build .jar artifact with dependencies?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, guava

After spending countless hours, googling similar threads and whatnot, i'm still stuck with this issue. I have simple Java app, that uses Guava. I'm using Intellij IDEA CE 2021. So, i have copied guava.jar in /lib, and included it in **Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies**:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK5xo.png)

I have also created .jar atrifact, and added guava dependency:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hixDk.png)

After building artifact and running it from console, i get ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/Files***, no matter what i try. I don't have any more ideas, any advice here?

Comment: have you tried using maven or a similar tool?

Comment: Convert your project to a Maven or Gradle project and just add Guava as dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/30.1.1-jre

Comment: I have never used maven/gradle, how can i convert it?

Comment: intellij has quite easy tools to do that, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html
but why do you use a professional IDE if you are just starting?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Don't worry, continue using IntelliJ. It's by far the best. There is no point learning some inferior tool, only to have to relearn how to do the same things in IntelliJ later. IntellIJ offers so many hints that a beginner might miss (comparing strings with == etc.). It has by far the best set of checks of any IDE. That alone makes it more beginner-friendly because you will spend less time chasing stupid bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple steps and you are done with this task:

1. put the guava.jar file in a directory inside the project (e.g. lib)
2. if you have just one dependency go in the project explorer and right-click on guava-30...jar and choose "Add as library"
3. if you know there are more dependencies right-click on the "lib" folder and choose "Add as library..."
4. File - Project Structure - Artifacts - press "+" - JAR - from Modules...
5. choose the Main class of your project and "OK"
6. generate the jar: Build - Build Artifacts - Build
7. you now have a folder in your project "out" - artifacts with the generated project jar

Just a note (not valid for Guava): if you are using **signed jars** like Bouncy Castle you will notice that this doesn't work like describes because the "including" of the external dependency file in the project jar will destroy the signature.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it, made fresh project, pasted code there, and did above steps.